# Finding the element with the lowest depth

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<div id="one" class="center">
    <div id="two" class="wrap">
        <div id="three" class="west">
            <div id="four" class="center"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="five" class="center"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

It's about a automatically generated layout. Now i'd like to adress specific elements like a path but ignore all "wrap" elments in between.

For example:

1. `center/center` should yield `#five`
2. `center/west` should yield `#three`
3. `center/west/center` should yield `#four`

I tried using two different selectors:

`$('.center .center')` but instead of returning `#five` it returns `[#four, #five]` which is of course correct for this selector but not what i want here.

`$('.center > .center')` this one returns `#five` which is what i want but when i try to apply the same form of selector to (2.) or (3.) like this: `$('.center > .west')` it will return nothing because of the `.wrap` element in between.

So a long explanation for a simple question. Is there a way to get something like:

`$('.center .center').lowestDepth()`

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that would do this that's part of the standard jQuery library. Seems like you may have to write your own plugin to do it.

Comment: `$('.center > .center')` cant give you #five notice it clearly.

Comment: `alert($('.center .wrap .center:eq(1)').attr('id'));`

Comment: And then what's wrong with using `$('.center .west .center')` to get #four? In fact, it looks like you already know how to target specific element so question is quite unclear imho. Why would you need this kind of method?

Comment: in all your three conditions it you replace the first `center`  with `wrap ` you will get the desired output

Comment: Maybe something like this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/86akdhnq/. You end up with a clone of your structure, minus the `.wrap` elements, that you can then query. Unfortunately you'd then need to query the actual DOM again (using the ID) to work with the element(s) identified.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist But what about poping last matched element, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/n713ob1q/  But i'm really not sure to see any purpose for this, why not using relevant CSS selector if the HTML markup is already known?

Comment: @A.Wolff Works for the specific HTML in the question, but would fail if the `#five` element came before, rather than after, the `#three` element: http://jsfiddle.net/n713ob1q/1/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ya and anyway loosing jQuery chaining. Indeed looks like i'm quite confused regarding question, my bad!

Comment: FInally i came to use jQuery `$.fn.parentsUntil()` and, unfortunately, deprecated jq object `selector` property: http://jsfiddle.net/wo8z3v8o/

Comment: I understand all the comments about "why not directly access it if the structure is known" or "what is the purspose". In face the structure is not known. This is just an example that describes the problem. There could be different "implementations" where the only thing that they have in common ist the structure of "center,west,north,south" elements. But there could be "wrap" elements of all kin din between that i don't know. And i still need to access it in a path like way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a built-in function in jQuery to do this out of the box, the
[.closest](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.closest) - method is somewhat similar, it just traverses up the DOM.

What you could do is call a function recursively and filter on the direct childs of an element and do so, until you found your closest element.

I made a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3yrk7dr/3/) to show this.

```
function lowestDepth(selector, elem){
    var childElements = elem.children();

    var filteredElements = childElements.filter(selector);

    if(filteredElements.length === 0){
       return lowestDepth(selector, childElements);
    } else {
       return filteredElements.eq(0);
    }
}


var elements = $('#one .west');
var ldelement = lowestDepth('.center', elements);
```

`.children()` traverses one level down in the DOM and returns matched elements, you could even pass a selector to it to filter elements in the same step, but I think the example is clearer this way.

The `elements` variable defines the "starting point", the first argument passed is the selector that the function looks for.

Note that this is a quick example to show you the idea behind this, this could be polished and optimized.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: Sorted it.

EDIT: Just noticed it's not actually doing it the way I expected it :D will try to improve and update.

I've come up with a solution. It works for the current structure, but haven't tested with different structure:

```
function findStuff(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
if ($('.' + arg1).children('.' + arg2).length == 0) {
    if ($('.' + arg1).children().first().attr('class') != arg2) {
        if(arg3 == null) {
            findStuff($('.' + arg1).children().first().attr('class'), arg2, null);
        } else {
            findStuff($('.' + arg1).children().first().attr('class'), arg2, arg3);
        }     
    }
} else {        
    if(arg3 != null) {
        findStuff(arg2, arg3, null); 
    } else {
        $('.' + arg1).children('.' + arg2).css('background-color', 'red'); 
    }
}
}
$(document).ready(function () {
findStuff("center", "center", null);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhs4c0cp/1/

First it looks for the first 2 sets of arguments and if there is a third argument, once the first element matching the original arg1 and arg2 is found, it will call itself with 2 new arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the work, but this limits the search to 3 levels of the tree. The tree could be deeper than in the example. But it seems to work for the specific situation.

Comment: In that case, you can probably modify the function to use an array of arguments.

Comment: @Chris Also just noticed that it wont matter if the html tree is deeper is deeper. It will work as long as you need to use 3 arguments https://jsfiddle.net/vhs4c0cp/3/